# VBA Excel: Is it possible to count horizontal page breaks in a named range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of automatically generated reports, each consisting 24 named ranges.

Each named range can't be broken by a horizontal page break.

My idea was to loop through all named ranges and count the page breaks within.

But I can't find a way to count page breaks within a named range.

Does anybody know if it is possible at all?

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions. Hopefully i can find the time to test it before Christmas, otherwise i will come back and answer in January.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. May simply scan named ranges and then rows of the range for already existing page breaks. But I am afraid it is  slow process and may take long time in file with many long named ranges. may please modify it according to your requirement.

```
Sub test()
Dim Rw As Range
Dim RngStr As String, Nm As Name

    For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    RngStr = Nm.Name
        For Each Rw In Range(RngStr).Rows
            If Rw.PageBreak <> xlNone Then
            Debug.Print RngStr & " on " & Range(RngStr).Address(, , , True) & " has a Pagebreak at Row " & Rw.Row
            End If
        Next Rw
    Next Nm

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Carrying on from my comment on @VBasic2008 answer, and blatantly pinching his `Intersect` idea I found this works:

```
Sub CountBreaks()

    Dim nr As Name
    Dim Hpb As HPageBreak
    Dim Vpb As VPageBreak
    Dim h As Long, v As Long

    'May need some method to look at a select number of named ranges.
    For Each nr In ThisWorkbook.Names

        For Each Hpb In nr.RefersToRange.Parent.HPageBreaks
            If Not Intersect(Range(Hpb.Location.Address).EntireRow, _
                             Range(nr.RefersToRange.Address)) Is Nothing Then
                h = h + 1
            End If
        Next Hpb

        For Each Vpb In nr.RefersToRange.Parent.VPageBreaks
            If Not Intersect(Range(Vpb.Location.Address).EntireColumn, _
                             Range(nr.RefersToRange.Address)) Is Nothing Then
                v = v + 1
            End If
        Next Vpb

        MsgBox nr.Name & " has: " & vbCr & _
            h & " horizontal page breaks." & vbCr & _
            v & " vertical page breaks.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation

        h = 0
        v = 0

    Next nr

End Sub
```

I hope I've got the sheet qualifications correct - i.e. I think `Range(Hpb.Location.Address)` refers to the correct sheet as well.

The `.PageSetup.PrintArea = nmAddress` in the comment wasn't needed - was just having problems because my sheet didn't have any data on it.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between HPBr (2 horizontal page breaks), and Sheet1!HPBr (3 horizontal page breaks)? I'm using your function on my workbook and I have only this one name.

Comment: Erm, probably my second to last paragraph explains that (does the address for HPBr cross 3 breaks when applied on a different sheet?)  I'll take another look at the code.

Comment: Is definitely saying `Sheet1!HPBr` and not `Sheet1!Print_Area`? (that's what I got with HPBr covering `Sheet1!B44:E56` so it crossed one H Page Break).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I added manully a HPB Name before. Sorry. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

## PB Hell

I suggest you study first this code for one named range, then you will easily create a loop for all of them.

```
Sub PageBr()

  Const cStrName As String = "HPBr"
  Const cStrRange As String = "B50:B250"
  Dim nmAddress As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer

  With Sheet1

    ' Define a name (Refers to ThisWorkbook (.Parent)).
    .Parent.Names.Add cStrName, .Range("B50:B250")
    nmAddress = .Parent.Names(cStrName).RefersToRange.Address

    ' Add horizontal pagebreaks.
    With .HPageBreaks
      .Add Before:=.Parent.Range("A59")
      .Add Before:=.Parent.Range("B159")
      .Add Before:=.Parent.Range("A248")
      .Add Before:=.Parent.Range("D269")
    End With

    ' Range version
    For i = 1 To .HPageBreaks.Count
      If Not Intersect(.Range(.HPageBreaks(i).Location.Address) _
          .Resize(, .Columns.Count), .Range(nmAddress)) Is Nothing Then
        j = j + 1
      End If
    Next
    Debug.Print "The named range '" & cStrName & "' contains " & j _
        & " horizontal pagebreaks."

    ' Row version
    Dim pbRow As Long
    Dim nmRow1 As Long
    Dim nmRow2 As Long

    nmRow1 = .Range(nmAddress).Row
    nmRow2 = .Range(nmAddress).Rows.Count + .Range(nmAddress).Row - 1

    j = 0
    For i = 1 To .HPageBreaks.Count
      pbRow = .Range(.HPageBreaks(i).Location.Address).Row
      If pbRow >= nmRow1 And pbRow <= nmRow2 - 1 Then
        j = j + 1
      End If
    Next
    Debug.Print "The named range '" & cStrName & "' contains " & j _
        & " horizontal pagebreaks."

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: [HPageBreaks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hpagebreaks) is a collection so you can step through it using a `For...Each` loop. While trying to test that I also found that If you add a page break that does not intersect the print area, then the newly-added `HPageBreak` object will not appear in the `HPageBreaks` collection for the print area. - my testing was failing because the count was 0. So might need `.PageSetup.PrintArea = nmAddress` before the loop and then could use: `Dim pb As HPageBreak:For Each pb In .HPageBreaks:j=j+1:Next pb`.